# What is DOM-based XSS?

Tags: javascript, dom, xss

DOM-based XSS is so poorly documented. I already know what reflected and stored XSS are.

Comment: you should ask this on http://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are good resources for it:

- [DOM Based XSS](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/DOM_Based_XSS)
- [Testing for DOM-based Cross site scripting](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_DOM-based_Cross_site_scripting_%28OWASP-DV-003%29)

> DOM Based XSS (or as it is called in
>   some texts, “type-0 XSS”) is an XSS
>   attack wherein the attack payload is
>   executed as a result of modifying the
>   DOM “environment” in the victim’s
>   browser used by the original client
>   side script, so that the client side
>   code runs in an “unexpected” manner.
>   That is, the page itself (the HTTP
>   response that is) does not change, but
>   the client side code contained in the
>   page executes differently due to the
>   malicious modifications that have
>   occurred in the DOM environment.

Comment: So is DOM-based XSS like a "JavaScript injection"?

Comment: @DT: Yes client side code is used in such manner for the malacious purpose.

Comment: @DT3, not exactly - its not injecting javascript, but forcing the existing javascript to inject [script into itself | HTML into the webpage].

Answer (score 3):

See http://www.owasp.org/index.php/DOM_Based_XSS

Basically, it's an attack aganist client-side scripts that fetch data from GET strings, the url, the fragment identifier or something like that and put it into the page without escaping it.

Answer (score 2):

[There's a good description and example at OWASP](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/DOM_Based_XSS)